# how to hide show div using radiobuttonlist in yii

Tags: html, yii, show-hide, radiobuttonlist

i have  a problem what i need to do is when select Yes on the radiobuttonlist it will show a div and if i select No it will remain hidden

```
<td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Is Scholarship?');?></td>
<!-- SCHOLAR -->
<td><?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'is_scholar',
                          array('Yes'=>'Yes', 'No'=>'No'));?>
<td><?php echo $form->error($model,'is_scholar');?></td>
```

on my view:

```
<div class="toggle-form-wrapper" style="display:none"  id="scholar">
  sd asds dasd asd asd asd sd asd asd
</div>
```

i used different method but ends up worng please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery. It is very easy. Fro ex:
Suppose you have the div with id as 'div1'.
And your yes and no button id is 'yes' & 'no' corresponding. Just write following Jquery to the thing work properly:

$('#yes').click(function(){
$('#div1').show();
});

$('#no').click(function(){
$('#div1').hide();
});

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem ? May be your JS file has some error code. Could you please check in error console.